# JasperReport and huge XML as data source

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm dealing with Jasper and HUGE reports. Just to give you an idea of how big the reports are, the XML that I'm feeding to the Jasper Report is 1Gb and I'm currently testing with 4Gb of memory.
At the moment I tried to se the `JaxenXmlDataSource` together with the property `"net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.executer.factory": "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.xml.JaxenXPathExecuterFactory"`, but no luck. Here is some code:

```
JRSwapFileVirtualizer swapFileVirtualizer = null;
if ("on".equalsIgnoreCase(jasperVirtualizerOn)) {
  JRSwapFile sf = new JRConcurrentSwapFile(jasperSwapFileDirectory, 1024, 100);
  swapFileVirtualizer = new JRSwapFileVirtualizer(100, sf, true);
  params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_VIRTUALIZER, swapFileVirtualizer);
}

InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourceXml.toFile()));
JaxenXmlDataSource ds = new JaxenXmlDataSource(is);

... set several parameters ...

JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(
                new ClassPathResource(path)
                        .getInputStream());
        
SimpleJasperReportsContext jasperReportsContext = new SimpleJasperReportsContext();
jasperReportsContext.setExtensions(RepositoryService.class, Collections.singletonList(new JasperResourceRepository()));
        JRPropertiesUtil.getInstance(jasperReportsContext).setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.executer.factory",
                "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.xml.JaxenXPathExecuterFactory");

JasperReport rep = JasperCompileManager.getInstance(jasperReportsContext).compileReport(design);

params.put(JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION, false);

JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager
                .getInstance(jasperReportsContext)
                .fill(jasperReport, parameters, ds);
```

The code already has problems when filling the report. I'm afraid that the Jaxen implementation of the `JRXmlDataSource` is not enough.

Thank you

Comment: You could use a pull/push XML parser and either write the JR data source yourself or store in DB tables, maybe an embedded client/server H2 database. You could also do something like `String.intern()`.

Comment: Notice that if UTF-8 is not needed you can have Strings using half the size, internally bytes in say Latin-1.

Comment: Thank you Joop, I was digging into the XalanJRDataSource and JaxenXmlDataSource. I saw that both keeps the Document object as parameter and I suppose that this Document actually represents the whole xml. Am I right? If that is the case I have to implement a custom chunk based JRXmlDataSource, but to be honest have no idea how. Do you have any experience on that?

Comment: Sorry, no time for that. There are XML parsers that do not create a full DOM document, but read through it. Basically like the old handler. Not the easiest way. I would use a database (like H2), because the development is easier, one problem part at a time. You can write a database scheme, fill data and check the report. Then convert the XML any way you like it, even with simple text parsing.

Comment: Hi Joop thank you! I will read through it.